# Kiwi unit tests never failing in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, kiwi

For some reason my tests are passing every time. Even when I add

```
fail(@"failed");
```

Xcode still says "test succeeded"

Any ideas?

Heres what my spec looks like

```
#import "SDRViewController.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Kiwi/Kiwi.h>

SPEC_BEGIN(SDRViewControllerSpec)

describe(@"SDRViewController", ^{
    __block SDRViewController *viewController = [[SDRViewController alloc]init];

    beforeAll(^{
        [viewController setupCollectionView];
    });
    describe(@"viewController.collectionView", ^{

        describe(@"collectionViewLayout", ^{
            UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)viewController.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
            [[flowLayout shouldNot]beNil];
            [[theValue(flowLayout.sectionInset) should]equal: theValue(UIEdgeInsetsZero)];
            fail(@"failed");
             });

        });
});

SPEC_END
```

Comment: If you are going to downvote the question, at least give some constructive criticism

Comment: Probably a dumb question but have you verified that the test itself is being run, either through a log statement or a breakpoint? What happens if you run the tests from the command line via [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool)?

Comment: Also, I notice that the test block itself is inside the `describe` method when Kiwi uses the `it` method for its test blocks. Could that be an issue?

Comment: @samsymons Yea. Its being run. Just not failing

Comment: I've been using `it` in the other tests I'm trying to write. Still not working though :(  I've had this problem for over a month now

Comment: After doing some more research, it looks like this is an issue on the kiwi page, and hasn't been fixed yet. https://github.com/kiwi-bdd/Kiwi/issues/589

Comment: Indeed there is a Kiwi issue that might explain the behaviour you noticed, however @samsymons has a point, at least give us valid code so we don't waste time chasing ghosts by trying to analyse incorrect code. Please post code that is relevant to the question, i.e. contains at `it`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can't fail as it contains no unit tests. Thus, there are zero failures, which Xcode considers as success. You should wrap the code you want to test within an `it` block:

```
describe(@"collectionViewLayout", ^{
    it(@"has a valid flow layout", ^{
        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)viewController.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
        [[flowLayout shouldNot]beNil];
        [[theValue(flowLayout.sectionInset) should]equal: theValue(UIEdgeInsetsZero)];
        fail(@"failed");
    });
});
```

If you want to learn more on the Kiwi blocks, there a good book on that: https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/test-driving-ios-development/id502345143?ls=1&mt=11.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there somewhere I could find out what each block does?

Comment: There's a book on Kiwi, it might help you understand the usually used blocks: https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/test-driving-ios-development/id502345143?ls=1&mt=11

Comment: Update: After reading the Kiwi unit testing book, I'm still getting this strange non-error. Take a look - https://vid.me/P4VD

Comment: That's strange, it looks like the tests fail as expected, and shortly after they get unmarked. Does the console give any hints like errors or exceptions, that could trigger this behavior?

Comment: The console is still displaying the same test failed messages.

Comment: Then there might be an Xcode bug  that's causing this, if the console prints the test results as expected.

Comment: I have the same problem. In my situation though, the test behaves properly the first time it is run - then things get messed up on a subsequent run. Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670235/ios-kiwi-testing-random-behaviour